# Discord.py bot react to user's next message after using a specific command

Tags: discord, discord.py

For example:
I use !react command and then after 1 min I send a message and then the bot reacts to the message with a specific emoji. Is it possible?

```
  @commands.command()
  @commands.cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.user)
  async def cookieme(self, ctx):
```

...somehow remembers to this name and next time the user say something it reacts to the msg with a cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question but I will try to help you:

```py
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):

  def check(message):
    return ctx.author == message.author and ctx.channel == message.channel
  react = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
  await react.add_reaction("")
```